# XSLT recursive boolean condition

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, recursion, boolean

I have a scenario where I use recursion to verify if a condition is true or false in a set of elements, when the condition for any element becomes false the whole condition is false.

I have used value-of to print true or false, however since it is recursive the output ends up something like "truefalsetruetrue". Due to this I made sure to only use value-of when the condition within the loop is false so the final output ends up something like "falsefalsefalsefalse". Due to this I check the length of the final output where an empty string signifies the overall condition was true and when not empty false is signified.

Is there a far more elegant way to do this where the param "data" directly receives a "true" or "false" output which can be directly be used to check if the overall condition was successful.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:param name="data">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Data">
            <xsl:with-param name="expression" select="true" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:param>
    <!--
        instead of a single false or true it will be like truefalsefalsetrue depending on the number of loops
        As a hack we check if the $data variable is an empty string or not where empty string signifies true
    -->
    <xsl:value-of select="$data=''" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Data">
    <xsl:param name="expression"/>
    <xsl:if test="$expression=true()">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Data" >
            <xsl:with-param name="expression" select="xpathCondition"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$expression=false()">
        <!-- we only output when there is false, so by doing this we can check if the output to the variable in the parent template is empty or not to then
        identify if the overall condition is false or true -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$expression" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps you should post a less abstract example that includes an input, a specific condition to test and the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do an overall check for the existence of:

```
Data [not($expression)]
```

---

### Edit:

> Is there any way to return one single true or false value to the
>   calling("/" template) template using recursion.

Probably not, because recursion runs in parallel on branches. We don't see your data, so we can only assume that is the case. In theory at least, you could force your own recursion order and exit with the first false result - but we would need to see your data in order to tell if and how it could be done.

A much simpler solution is to evaluate the results of the recursion to a Boolean result, for example as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="contains ($data, 'false')"/>
```

This is not a hack, just a necessity due to the way recursion works.

Comment: Hi, this is a bit more complex and recursion is required and I cannot simply use a Xpath query here in this case. Is there any way to return one single true or false value to the calling("/" template) template using recursion.

Comment: "*I cannot simply use a Xpath query here in this case.*" Are you sure about this? I find it difficult to envision a case where you can pass the the test expression as a parameter, but cannot use the same as a predicate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 1.0 then one approach is to return "" to mean true, and "F" to mean false, and then the overall result is false if the final string is not equal to "".

In XSLT 2.0 a cleaner approach is to have your templates return a boolean value, and use the XPath 2.0 `some $x in ... satisfies` construct for the existential logic.